# Pertubed equation of linear complementarity problem

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Problem: For given $q \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, consider the $LCP(M,q)$ problem find $z \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that
\begin{align*}
 &z,w \ge 0,\\
 &z^T w  = 0,\\
 & w = Mz + q
\end{align*}

and the sequence of the following perturbed equations:
\begin{align*}
&w = Mz + q\\
&w'z = \mu e. \tag{1}
\end{align*}

My question: What is condition for the existence of a solution of this problem. Besides, why LCP problem has a solution then system (1) has unique solution for each $\mu >0$.